# How to add a plain text certificate to a java keytool cacerts cert store

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool

Recently, someone asked me to add key like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDT.....
.....
.....w8XMWhBI=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

to my keystore.

Before, I was usually adding a file like a .pem file to keystore so adding just bunch of text like this to keystore was bit confusing to me and I could not find much info online, so I decided to create SO and provide solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- **First of all, why I got only text like above in my email and not the
  actual .pem file?**  It turns out Outlook was blocking pem file so all
  the user could send me is the text above.
- **How to add this certificate text to keystore?**  Just copy the text
  including the entire lines containing the BEGIN CERTIFICATE/END CERTIFICATE text into a file, then save that file (name
  is however you wish) with .pem extension like **my.cert.file.tls.pem**.

Now you can use java keytool to add the .pem certificate to your java keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias my.cert.file.tls -keystore ./cacerts -file C:\me\my.cert.file.tls.pem
```

To confirm the pem certificate is imported, use

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

I did all this in OpenJdk11.

Comment: That won't work because files that start with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` are base64 encoded RFC 5280 SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) formatted public keys. They are not certificates and their format is not compatible with a certificate.

Comment: What does *wrapped in a .pen Av* mean? Also, reviewing answers for incorrect information is an important task so, no, I won't be dissuaded from doing that.

Comment: Have you read my question/answer? It says it right there

Comment: You edited your comment to correct what were evidently typos.

Comment: Just double-checked, when importing a public key file starting with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` into `cacerts` keytool returns an error `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`

Comment: I have not had any issues issuing ```keytool -import -alias my.cert.file.tls -keystore ./cacerts -file C:\me\my.cert.file.tls.pem``` to import this pem file into my openJdk11 cacerts.  ```keytool -list -keystore cacerts``` confirmed that the generated .pem file got inmported without any issue.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am seeing now your point, these are not easy to handle when doing it on a mobile device.  It is not BEGIN PUBLIC KEY / END PUBLIC KEY.  It is BEGIN CERTIFICATE / END CERTIFICATE.  I updated post.  The wrong one was copied from another SO question and it had different 1st and last line